# Why is it "The King's Speech" but "Le Discours d'un Roi"?

Tags: definite-articles

In the movie's Wikipedia article, there is [a French poster of the movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aAffiche_Internationale_juane_The_King%27s_Speech.jpg), which says "Le Discours d'un Roi". This is interesting to me because the French title uses the indefinite article "un" to refer to the king, which in my view makes more sense because he's just a king and from the title alone it's not obvious which king we are talking about.

Is it more appropriate that the English title use the definite article? Is it because the king is British?

Comment: This isn't really on-topic for this site.

Comment: Why? It's about the usage of definite article in English, which I think is on-topic.

Comment: First of all, it's asking about a translation. Second, you're asking why someone chose a certain set of words for a movie title. Whoever did so could have chosen the definite or the indefinite article, but no one here can tell you why they made the choice.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your suggestion. I changed the description of the question so that it will not sound like I am asking why they use it. I mentioned the translation for comparison only, not exactly the subject of my question.

Comment: I still don't believe this question is relevant. It's totally a subjective discussion that only the producer of the movie could settle. "King's Speech," "The Speech of a King," "A King's Speech," and "The King's Speech," for example, all sound just fine to me.

Comment: how could a question about the appropriate usage of grammatical rules be subjective?

Comment: I assumed that 'speech' referred to George VI's manner of speaking, involving a stammer. It never occurred to me that 'speech' in the title meant the radio broadcast he had to make. I've just asked my wife and she thought the same thing. In English 'speech' could mean either. However the French translation, by employing 'discours', clearly means a specific 'speech'i.e.  the radio broadcast. But if 'speech' referred to his manner of speaking the correct French would have been 'L'Articulation d'un Roi' or 'L'élocution d'un Roi'. Has the translator got it right?

Comment: @WS2, interesting! I always assumed it referred to a speech given at some point. But then again, I am a bit of a lout when it comes to history, and I didn’t even know the film was about George VI, nor that he had a stammer …

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specifically in Britain, at least, the convention of "The King's something or other", has a very long tradition.  Any number of things of all sorts are attributed in this way.  For instance, The King's Men, the acting company to which Shakespeare belonged.  Other examples, include, The King's Regiment, The King's School, and The King's Breakfast, to name just a few.

Interestingly enough, despite the above, the Film is actually based on a play call A King's Speech, so what the hell do I know.

Comment: +1, to me "The King's _" just means the current King, whomever that is.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question which was about why the indefinite article rather than the definite is attached to 'King'. It WAS NOT ABOUT why the word 'speech' attracts the definite article in the French but no article in English. This latter has nothing whatever to do with Royal etiquette, but everything to do with the fact that French nouns demand articles where English nouns don't. e.g. 'I love bananas' translates as 'J'aime les bananes'. Also the French method of applying the possessive would require an article even if spoken in English - 'The Speech of the King'.

Answer (score 1):

It may well be, as you said, because the movie is about the British king.

In English usage (on both sides of the Atlantic), "the Queen" - without further specification - is commonly understood to refer to Elizabeth II of the United Kingdom, the only monarch of an English-speaking country.

So for the timeframe in which the movie is set, "the King" would probably indeed be understood the same way. By contrast, in French "le Roi" would probably require some kind of modifier.

Comment: To be technically correct -- [the best kind of correct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_Hermes_Requisitioned_His_Groove_Back) -- the current monarch is only Elizabeth **II** *of England*.  As any good Scotsman can tell you, she is the first of that name to sit on the throne of the United Kingdom since that realm was formed in 1707.  She's QE2 of England and Wales but QE the First of the UK.  And Canada and Jamaica and New Zealand and Barbados and about 20 other places...

Comment: @Malvolio, really? Odd, then, that Canadian coins read "ELIZABETH II" on the obverse.

Comment: @msh21O, Malvolio is technically correct because Scotland was added to the United Kingdom with the crowning of King James in 1603, as he was also King James VI of Scotland.  He succeeded... Elizabeth I (who had condemn his mother to death).  In case you didn't know that story  of course.

Comment: @Alain Pannetier, what's with the coins, then?

Comment: @msh210, you are perfectly right the coins of course don't take these trivialities into consideration.  The easiest way to think of it is that the first Queen named Elizabeth also Queen of Canada Scotland and other places is Elizabeth II of England.

Comment: @Malvolio, +1 for the Futurama reference.

Comment: @Malvolio et al: Just because a place has an Elizabeth II doesn't mean it previously had an Elizabth I. For instance, France had Louis XVI and Louis XVII but no Louis XVII, and Napoléon I and III but not II. There the royalist/Bonapartist numbering took even though the regimes fell.

Comment: France certainly did have a Louis XVII! Louis-Charles Capet became King Louis XVII on 21 January, 1793 at the moment Madame Guillotine gave Louis XVI his famously close shave.  Similarly, Napoléon II reigned from 22 June to 7 July, 1815.  Both rulers were children (Napoléon was only four years old) and in the hands of their enemies (Louis was extrajudicially murdered by the French government) but they were kings.  Elizabeth II falls into the same category of *Aliens³* and *Rambo III* -- beneficiaries all of numbering schemes that were clearly wrong but useful and not utterly without support.

Comment: And, to bring us partly back to english.stackexchange.com -- James has the distinction of being the eponym of *two* cities in New York State.  I'll leave it to you all to deduce which two they are.

Comment: Thanks Malvolio for the history knowledge.. It's very interesting (and pleasant) that there are a lot of history experts in this SE and history discussion in the comments :)

Comment: by the way have you guys checked the [history SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5169/history) ?

Comment: @Malvolio One thing I can tell you is that the Japanese, (who think she is even more fab than David Beckham or The Beatles) call her Elizatheth ll.

Comment: @Malvolio, I was under the impression (formed, I admit, by _QI_) that any monarch of the United Kingdom will take the number following the highest-numbered predecessor _in any country_ within the UK as his or her regal number. So Elizabeth is Elizabeth II in the entire UK because the previously highest one was QEI of England; and if there is a future King James, he will be James IX of the United Kingdom, since the last James was VIII of Scotland and III of England. Highest previous number plus one.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet -- that seems to be the rule (William IV and George III both followed it), but it isn't clear whether the rule is one plus the highest number, or the highest number *in England*.  If there's ever a King David III or King Malcolm V of the UK, then we'll know.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is partly due to the fact that *Le Discours d'un Roi* sounds much better than *Un Discours du Roi*.  Also in Great Britain, he is always addressed as *The* king to emphasize his superiority.

Comment: The suggestion is not 'Un Discours du Roi' but ' Le Discours du Roi', as opposed to 'Le Discours d'un Roi'

Comment: We appreciate your answer. You can make this a better answer by providing links, even in answers responding to seemingly opinion-based questions. :)